# How to debug if a non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, variables, undefined, opencart2.x

I am getting

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/zeefashcp/public_html/catalog/model/bossthemes/boss_tagcloud.php on line 37.

Line:37 `"$spread = $max_qty - $min_qty;"`

```
<?php
class ModelBossthemesBossTagCloud extends Model {

    public function getRandomTags($limit = 5, $min_font_size = 9, $max_font_size = 25, $font_weight) {
        $product_id = array();
        $names          = array();
        $totals         = array();
        $tags           = array();
        $tagcloud       = false;

        $tagNameQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description WHERE language_id=" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id'));

        if (count($tagNameQuery->rows) > 0) {
            foreach ($tagNameQuery->rows as $row) {
                if($row['tag']){
                    $names = explode(',', $row['tag']);
                    $totals = array_merge($totals, $names);
                }
            }
            $tags = array_slice($totals, 0, $limit); 
            if($tags){
                $tagcloud = $this->generateTagCloud($tags, true, $min_font_size, $max_font_size, $font_weight);
            }
        }

        return $tagcloud;
    }

    private function generateTagCloud($tags, $resize = true, $min_font_size = 9, $max_font_size = 25, $font_weight) {

        if ($resize == true) {
            arsort($tags);

            $max_qty = max(array_values($tags));
            $min_qty = min(array_values($tags));

            $spread = $max_qty - $min_qty;

            if ($spread == 0) { $spread = 1; }

            $step = ((int)$max_font_size - (int)$min_font_size) / ($spread);

            $cloud = array();

            foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
                $size=rand((int)$min_font_size,(int)$max_font_size);

                $cloud[] = '<a href="' . $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . $value) . '" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:' . $size . 'px;font-weight:' . $font_weight . ';" title="">' . $value . '</a> ';
            }

        } else {

            foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
                $cloud[] = '<a href="' . $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . $value) . '" style="text-decoration:none;" title="">' . $value . '</a> ';
            }
        }

        $tagcloud = '';

        shuffle($cloud);

        for ($x = 0; $x < count($cloud); $x++) {
            $tagcloud .= $cloud[$x];
        }

        return $tagcloud;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Either `$max_qty` or `$min_qty` is not a number. Log/var_dump/echo to check what it is.

Comment: `array_values` is either returning an empty array so `min` or `max` returns `false` or `min` or `max` is returning a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your $tags array contains only strings, with probably at least one non-numeric string, so the functions min() and max() don't return an integer but a string.

That's why `$spread = $max_qty - $min_qty;` doesn't work.

Here is an extract of the PHP documentation (function min()) :

> multiple non-numeric string values will be compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned will be of the original type with no conversion applied.

[PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)

Since I don't know what your trying to do, nor what your tags looks like, I cannot help you further.